# How do I fill an array with unique random numbers in different rows/columns

Tags: c#, arrays, random, integer, autofill

I've looked around quite a bit now but cant seem to find a satisfying answer. I would like to fill a 5x5 with unique numbers. In column 1 it can only be a number between 1-5 and in column 2 number 16-30 and so on up until column 5 with a number between 61-75. Its a bingo board. I've tried a couple of things but none of them works, I cant seem to find a way of filling the arrays with my specifications. Everywhere I look it's only examples of prefilled arrays with a few numbers or the code is way to advanced for me.

I created a program a while ago that creates an regular array with the numbers 1-75 and then shuffles it with fisher/yates algorithm. Is this something i should continue to use or should I start from the scratch?`enter code here`

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string choise = "";
    while (choise != "q" && choise != "Q")
    {

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("[1] for a random row of numbers! \n[2] to start the game! 
        \n[Q] to quit! \nPress enter after your selection.");
        choise = Console.ReadLine();
        if (choise == "1")
        {
            RandomNum.randomTal();
        }

  (another class)
  static  Random rnd = new Random();
   public static void Shuffle<T>(T[] array)
    {
        Console.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            int r = i + (int)(rnd.NextDouble() * (array.Length - i));
            T t = array[r];
            array[r] = array[i];
            array[i] = t;
        }
    }

(and another class)

class RandomNum
  {
    public static void randomTal()
    {
        int[] sifferArray = Enumerable.Range(1, 56).ToArray();
        shuffle.Shuffle(sifferArray);
        foreach (var item in sifferArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to go back.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: fisher/yates algorithm should be perfect.  Say you want 5 *unique* random numbers between 16 and 30.  Do `Enumerable.Range(16,15).ToArray().Shuffle().Take(5);`

Comment: Im sorry but I don't really know what do do with that. If i try and put in the RandomNum class it says "; expected" under the shuffle. And the enumerable doesn't work on 2d arrays i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bingoCard = getBingoCard();
        int colNum = 1;

        foreach (var col in bingoCard)
        {
            Console.Write("col" + colNum.ToString() + " ");
            foreach (var item in col)
            {
                Console.Write(item + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            colNum++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
            {
                Console.Write(bingoCard[y][x].ToString() + (bingoCard[y][x] > 9 ?  " " : "  "));
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }



    public static int[][] getBingoCard()
    {
        var randGen = new Random();
        var bingoCard = new int[][]{
        new int[5],
        new int[5],
        new int[5],
        new int[5],
        new int[5]
    };
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            {
                var possibleNumber = randGen.Next((15 * y) + 1, ((y + 1) * 15));
                while (bingoCard[y].Any(num => num == possibleNumber))
                {
                    possibleNumber = randGen.Next((15 * y) + 1, ((y + 1) * 15));
                }
                bingoCard[y][x] = possibleNumber;
            }
        }
        return bingoCard;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you guys! I really appreciate it! But on this last post I can't seem to understand how the math in the .next() is working. I know how to count it in "real" math. But i don't understand how it works here and what the numbers do. Would you like to explain it to a beginner please?

Comment: And also this code don't generate unique numbers in the arrays.

Comment: How do you mean it doesnt generate unique numbers?  Have you run it?  It generates unique numbers...

Comment: The math in the next() is to specify the min and max number to generate.  So the first column it calculates you should get a min of 1 and a max of 15.  On the second loop (second column) it adds 15 to each of those numbers... The min is 16 and the max is 30 (so on through each loop/column).  The while(any) loop forces the number generator to create a new number until a unique one for the array is found.

Comment: Oh sorry, I had edited the code on my own and therefore there was some duplicate numbers. But the original worked as it should. I want the numbers to go vertically lika a column? So tried to change the x's and y's in different combos, but then the code didn't work as it was supposed to. Do you have any pointers for me? Thanks for the help and explanation.

Comment: You just change how you write it to the screen...   edited answer above to render both

Comment: Thanks again. Just one more thing. The  >9 and :, what are they called they seem have a good function in the write(). But i don't understand how they work.

Comment: Thats the ternary operator.  Its a shorthand for if(){}else{} .  basically i was adding an extra space for single digit numbers so everything lined up.

Answer (score 0):

When I have a need for that, I use something like this:

```
   private int[] generatePermutation(int size, int seed) 
   {
        var permutation = new int[size];
        Rnd random = new Rnd(seed);

        List<int> permList = new List<int>(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) permList.Add(i);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            int index = random.Next(0, permList.Count);
            permutation[i] = permList[index];
            permList.RemoveAt(index);
        }
        return permutation;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class `BingoBoard` with an embedded 2d integer array corresponding to the cells, you could generate random patterns of cells like so:

```
public class BingoBoard
{
    public const int BoardDimension = 5;

    readonly int[,] board = new int[BoardDimension, BoardDimension];

    public BingoBoard()
    {
        // In column 1 it can only be a number between 1-15 and in column 2 number 16-30 and so on up until column 5 with a number between 61-75.
        for (int iRow = 0; iRow < board.GetLength(0); iRow++)
        {
            var col = Enumerable.Range(iRow * 3 * board.GetLength(1) + 1, 3 * board.GetLength(1)).Shuffle().Take(board.GetLength(1)).ToArray();
            for (int iCol = 0; iCol < board.GetLength(1); iCol++)
                board[iRow, iCol] = col[iCol];
        }
    }

    public int[,] Board
    {
        get
        {
            return board;
        }
    }
}

public static class RandomProvider
{
    // Adapted from http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx
    private static int seed = Environment.TickCount;

    [ThreadStatic]
    static Random random;

    public static Random GetThreadRandom()
    {
        if (random == null)
            random = new Random(Interlocked.Increment(ref seed));
        return random;
    }
}

public class FisherYatesShuffle 
{
    public void ShuffleInPlace<T>(T[] array)
    {
        var randomizer = RandomProvider.GetThreadRandom();

        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm , second version.
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
            var j = randomizer.Next(i, array.Length); // i = inclusive lower bound; array.Length = The exclusive upper bound of the random number returned
            array.Swap(i, j);
        }
    }
}

public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        var scrambled = list.ToArray();
        new FisherYatesShuffle().ShuffleInPlace(scrambled);
        return scrambled;
    }

    public static void Swap<T>(this T[] list, int i, int j)
    {
        if (list == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (i != j)
        {
            T temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[j];
            list[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```